# Find out which of the multiple conditions is true

Tags: bash, shell, if-statement, multiple-conditions

I have a script that will check for multiple conditions in if statement and run a desired command if its true.

```
  if [ ! -f /tmp/a ] && [ ! -f /tmp/b  ]; then
        touch /tmp/c  else 
        echo "file exists"  fi
```

I would now need to know which out of the multiple condition was true. 
Eg:  /tmp/a or /tmp/b which ever existed. Is there a way to get that in my else condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your `if` is using a compound condition, there is no way for `else` to figure out which part of the compound condition failed.  You could rewrite your code this way:

```
a_exists=0
b_exists=0
[[ -f /tmp/a ]] && a_exists=1 # flag set to 1 if /tmp/a exists
[[ -f /tmp/b ]] && b_exists=1 # flag set to 1 if /tmp/b exists
if [[ $a_exists == 0 && $b_exists == 0 ]]; then
  touch /tmp/c
else
  [[ $a_exists == 1 ]] && echo "a exists"
  [[ $b_exists == 1 ]] && echo "b exists"
fi
```

The above code can be written even more concisely with the Bash arithmetic operator `(( ... ))`:

```
a_exists=0
b_exists=0
[[ -f /tmp/a ]] && a_exists=1 # flag set to 1 if /tmp/a exists
[[ -f /tmp/b ]] && b_exists=1 # flag set to 1 if /tmp/b exists
if !((a_exists + b_exists)); then
  touch /tmp/c
else
  ((a_exists)) && echo "a exists"
  ((b_exists)) && echo "b exists"
fi
```

Comment: could you please explain? I am quite confused :)

Comment: Basically, we use two flags which are set based on file existence.  Then, the if-else block will use those flags without having to worry about how they were set.

Comment: oh, it was new to me that we can set  [[ ]]  with out if and also setting flags like this. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

This smells like one day there will be more than two files to check. Use a loop:

```
i_am_happy=yeah
for f in a b
do
    if [[ ! -f /tmp/$f ]]
    then
      echo "Criminy! No $f in tmp!"  # or what else you would like to do.
      i_am_happy=nope
    fi
done
[[ i_am_happy == nope ]] && touch /tmp/c
```